# Define String Node in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


/* data variable is used to store data as name 
suggests,the "next" is a pointer of the type node
that is used to point to the next node of the 
Linked List*/
/*
* Node Declaration
*/
struct node
{
  string info;
  struct node *next;
}*start;

/*
 * Class Declaration
*/
class single_llist
{
  public:
    node* create_node(string);
    void insert_begin();
    void insert_pos();
    void insert_last(); 
    void delete_pos();
    void sort();
    void search();
    void update();
    void reverse();
    void display();
    single_llist() 
    {
        start = NULL;
    }
};

/*
* Inserting element in beginning
*/
void single_llist::insert_begin()
{
  string value;
  cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
  cin>>value;
  struct node *temp, *p;
  temp = create_node(value);
  if (start == NULL)
  {
    start = temp;
    start->next = NULL;          
  } 
  else
  {
    p = start;
    start = temp;
    start->next = p;
  }
  cout<<"Element Inserted at beginning"<<endl;
}
```

I'm developing my program with Dev C ++ program.I trying to entering specific words to txt file and save them.Therefore I'm dealing with string.The program gives this error: `undefined reference to single_llist::create_node(std::string)` and showing me that there is mistake here, `temp = create_node(value);`I still researching what I need to do for solving this problem?

Comment: Did you define the function `create_node`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @NathanOliver I think I tried to wrong way without creating node first.For creating node check following code fragment.

```
/*
* Creating Node
*/
node *single_llist::create_node(string value)
{
struct node *temp, *s;
temp = new(struct node); 
if (temp == NULL)
{
    cout<<"Memory not allocated "<<endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    temp->info = value;
    temp->next = NULL;     
    return temp;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supposed to be an answer or an addendum to the question. If this is more information for the question, please use the edit link beneath the question, add this information to the question, and then delete this answer. If this is an answer, it needs a lot more explanation.

Comment: Yes,for me is an answer. Because `undefined reference to single_llist::create_node(std::string)` error was due to the absence of create_node function.And also I gave a piece of code on the node creation may also be useful to other friends. Thanks @user4581301